# Authorization in Web API using request headers or User?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm using API keys to secure an ASP.NET Core 2.2 API. Info about my allowed clients is loaded from appsettings and I have middleware that retrieves the key from the request header and verifies it. I want to add scopes to my clients and use them to restrict endpoint access. In the middleware I was planning to add the scopes to the request header but it occurred to me that I could simply create a User and add the scopes as role claims. That would allow me to use the familiar roles based authorization on my endpoints. Is this a bad idea?

Snip from my middleware InvokeAsync method:

```
if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("ApiKey", out var apiKey))
{
    if (_clientConfiguration.TryGetApiClient(apiKey, out var apiClient))
    {
        // this
        var claims = apiClient.Scopes.Split(',').Select(x => new Claim("Role", x)).ToList();
        claims.Add(new Claim("Name", apiClient.Name));
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "APIKEY", "Name", "Role");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        context.User = principal;

        // or this with policy based authorization downstream
        context.Request.Headers.Add("Scopes", apiClient.Scopes);

        await _next(context);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would stick to the framework standard so that it can be integrated well with other libraries. Designing your own mechanism is fine but it's just unnecessary especially when you just need a simpler code (compared to the standard way)..

Comment: @Hopeless What is the standard way? There is nothing built into the framework for authenticating with API keys that I'm aware of. This is internal to the API, there's no concern about integration.

Comment: I mean about the first way (using `User`). That's the standard way of setting a signed-in user.

Comment: @Hopeless This is an API so the User is a system, not a person. I haven't seen this approach used with an API but maybe that's the best way.

Comment: `User` property is what you always set (in the standard way) no matter what/how you use/do to authenticate before. I'm surprised that you have never seen something like that implemented.